# Stokes Flow over Sphere

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to re-create picture of Stokes Flow over Sphere by using Tikz. Can anyone help me? Many thanks. [image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Welcome! I agree to TobiBS. Though, for the beginning, check out the examples like [this](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/spacetime/) to get into the topic. And then, if you cannot produce a specific feature of your graphic, feel free to come back and someone will be glad to help out!

Answer (score 4):

I give you again my welcome to TeX.SE. Accepting the comments from the users, I add my manual creation  with [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor), which I always recommend to use it when the question is to ask to create figures to other users of this site.

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Circle [id:dp44150583447616754] 
\draw   (201,167.5) .. controls (201,128.56) and (232.56,97) .. (271.5,97) .. controls (310.44,97) and (342,128.56) .. (342,167.5) .. controls (342,206.44) and (310.44,238) .. (271.5,238) .. controls (232.56,238) and (201,206.44) .. (201,167.5) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9305050574046534] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (271.5,167.5) -- (342.86,86.21) ;
\draw [shift={(345.5,83.2)}, rotate = 491.28] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (11.61,-5.58) -- (0,0) -- (11.61,5.58) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7715572459907221] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 65; green, 117; blue, 5 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (345.5,83.2) -- (367.89,57.23) ;
\draw [shift={(370.5,54.2)}, rotate = 490.76] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 65; green, 117; blue, 5 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (11.61,-5.58) -- (0,0) -- (11.61,5.58) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6840835491832504] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (345.5,83.2) -- (305.57,49.77) ;
\draw [shift={(302.5,47.2)}, rotate = 399.94] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (11.61,-5.58) -- (0,0) -- (11.61,5.58) -- cycle    ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp020731002226342943] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (302.22,140.42) .. controls (304.65,141.75) and (306.9,143.52) .. (308.84,145.72) .. controls (314.27,151.9) and (316.03,160.05) .. (314.27,167.49) -- (290.5,161.86) -- cycle ; \draw  [line width=1.5]  (302.22,140.42) .. controls (304.65,141.75) and (306.9,143.52) .. (308.84,145.72) .. controls (314.27,151.9) and (316.03,160.05) .. (314.27,167.49) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4706764762391842] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 128; green, 128; blue, 128 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (441.5,167.2) -- (274.5,167.49) ;
\draw [shift={(271.5,167.5)}, rotate = 359.9] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 128; green, 128; blue, 128 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (306.44,139.48) -- (299.62,138.24) -- (302.72,144.44) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7974450172430716] 
\draw    (271.5,167.5) -- (228.44,116.49) ;
\draw [shift={(226.5,114.2)}, rotate = 409.83000000000004] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da09728632096048084] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (164.5,167.49) -- (81.5,167.2) ;
\draw [shift={(167.5,167.5)}, rotate = 180.2] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;

% Text Node
\draw (112,144.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\vec{v}_{\infty}$};
% Text Node
\draw (360,72.1) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\vec{v}_{R}$};
% Text Node
\draw (308,67) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\vec{v}_{\phi}$};
% Text Node
\draw (237,139.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\vec{a}$};
% Text Node
\draw (425,143.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\vec{F}$};
% Text Node
\draw (316,134.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\phi$};
% Text Node
\draw (292,109.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\vec{R}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Stokes Flow over Sphere}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]